# Can I prevent Facebook app requests from being visible in a browser?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, desktop

I have a Facebook app which has iOS and Android builds, and thus have setup native iOS and Android settings for the Facebook app.

I also have a PC build of the app, and have set up the Facebook app to also be 'Website with Facebook login', so that I can do authentication from the PC build (by opening the url

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://example.com/myRedirectPage.html&response_type=token
```

For the authentication to work from the PC build, as I said I had to set up 'Website with Facebook login', and set the url as "http://example.com/" - so my PC login is allowed to redirect to myRedirectPage.html (which then passes the information back to my PC app).

The problem now is that when I send an app request to a friend, because I've said that the Facebook app supports 'Website with Facebook Login', the app request appears in a browser for my friend, and if they 'Accept' the request, then they are redirected to http://example.com/?request_ids=XXXXXXXXXX

I only want the Facebook requests to redirect to the iOS or Android builds, and if the user cannot be redirected to those locations (ie. they are viewing Facebook in a browser/on PC), then they shouldn't be able to either see the request to begin with, or not be able to redirect.

Is this possible? Or, alternatively, is there a better way of doing the PC authentication without needing to set up a 'Website with Facebook login'?

Comment: Have you enabled deep links for your app? See the iOS docs here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/link-to-your-native-app-ios-sdk/ and the Android docs here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/link-to-your-native-app/